# JScrollPane override setHvalue

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I would like to modify my JScrollPane so that when the horizontal position is changed, the position hvalue is sent to another class. I don't want the other class to have to retrieve this value every time as this will happen repeatedly during a task which must be finished as quickly as possible.
I haven't been able to find any documentation on the exact syntax used by default but I'm guessing what I want will look something like this:

```
import java.lang.Math.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class scroll {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    panel p = new panel();
    
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(p,21,31) {
        @Override
        public final void setHvalue(double value) {
            hvalue = value;
            p.sendH((int) Math.round(value));
        }
    };
    
    f.add(sp);
    f.setSize(333,333);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

which will include a panel object governed by the class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class panel extends JPanel {

private static int H;
public panel() {}

public static void sendH(int x) {
    H=x;
    System.out.println(x);
}
}
```

Attempting to compile this code yields the error messages:

- scroll.java.11: error: method does not override or implement a method from supertype
- @Override
- scroll.java.13: error: cannot find symbol
- hvalue = value;
- symbol: variable hvalue

which, as I understand it, is basically their way of saying I can't modify setHvalue(). Is there some way around this or an alternative way of sending hvalue when it's changed instead of retrieving it every time it's needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when the horizontal position is changed, the position hvalue is sent to another class.

This is done by adding an `AdjustmentListener` to the horizontal scrollbar.

However, this is extra overhead that is NOT required if you do not use the information every time it changes.

I do not recommend using this approach.

> I don't want the other class to have to retrieve this value every time as this will happen repeatedly during a task which must be finished as quickly as possible.

Invoking the `getValue()` method of the scrollbar will NOT add any measurable overhead to your task.

Your task just needs a reference to the scroll pane so you can access the scrollbar and get the current value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured out the answer, sorry about that. It turns out that the method getHvalue is only for awt ScrollPane and is not inherited by swing JScrollPane. I will post a working version here, in case someone else is interested some day (although I'm guessing that camickr's approach is better).
The JScrollPane class is:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.accessibility.*;

public class scroll {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    panel p = new panel() {
        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize(){
            return new Dimension(getWidth(),getHeight());
        }
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
            return new Dimension(getWidth(),getHeight());
        }
        @Override
        public Dimension getMaximumSize(){
            return new Dimension(getWidth(),getHeight());
        }
    };
    
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(p,22,32);
    sp.setHorizontalScrollBar( new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL){
        @Override
        public void setValue(int value) {
            BoundedRangeModel m = getModel();
            int oldValue = m.getValue();
            m.setValue(value);

            if (accessibleContext != null) {
                accessibleContext.firePropertyChange(
                AccessibleContext.ACCESSIBLE_VALUE_PROPERTY,
                Integer.valueOf(oldValue),
                Integer.valueOf(m.getValue()));
            }
            
            p.sendH(value);
        }
    });
    
    f.add(sp);
    f.setSize(333,333);
    p.setSize(400,400);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

and the panel class is:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class panel extends JPanel {

private static int H;
public panel() {}

public static void sendH(int x) {
    H=x;
    System.out.println(x);
}
}
```

Comment: (1-) As explained above, if you want to be notified in a change of position of a scroll bar you use the AdjustmentListener. Don't override components when a solution already exists in the API.